# Removing a Windows Server Cluster Node and Then Adding Back - Do I need to remove the Availability Group replica?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

We had a secondary server bite the dust... we were remarkably able to resurrect it. Everything is great and intact... except for the windows server cluster configuration. We basically need to evict it and add it back...

I was thinking.. we could stop SQL services on this secondary replica, do the cluster work (evict / re-add) and then once the WSFC is happy for this node, start sql services back up... databases continue syncing as normal.

Or... would we need to completely remove the secondary replica from the AG and then rebuild everything?

Thanks for thoughts!

Comment: Original idea worked great.Thanks for the input! Sometimes its just reassuring to bounce ideas off the community. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first approach should work, subject to condition the WSFC is working fine. If AG sync does not works then you would have to re sync it from scratch. – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/42379

Make sure that you don't lose the Quorum when you evict that node. If the quorum is not lost, then everything should work fine without removing the node from the AG. Keep in mind that there will be no log truncation until that other node come back (as the AG sync will be suspended). If you have some really highly active database in those AGs, you may want to remove them to avoid log disk to fill. – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/105483